# Question about partition changes when reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation, partitioning

OK, so I have a dual-boot setup with Windows XP and Ubuntu 14.10.  I tried to do a system upgrade (from within 14.10) to Ubuntu 16.04, but I ran into problems, so I'm doing a fresh reinstall of 16.04.

Here's where things get tricky.  I have two physical drives:
the first (sda) has the Windows partition on it.  The second drive (sdb) has three partitions:  a non-system partition that contains just data/files (sdb1), the second one with the Ubuntu system (sdb5), and a third that is a swap partition (sdb6).  When I specify "Erase Ubuntu 14.10 and reinstall," a warning pops up, telling me that changes will be made to certain partitions--that's understandable, since I'm erasing and reinstalling--but I can't tell exactly which partitions the installer plans to tamper with!

I do know that the target partitions are on the second physical disk (it mentions the "sdb" label), but the warning popup only refers to the target partitions using numbers (e.g., partition 5) instead of their "sdb" notation (e.g., sdb5) which I cannot find anywhere else and do not correspond to their sdb label...so I'm uncertain if the installer is simply going to "automagically" reuse the partitions already allocated to Ubuntu and the swap file (which would make logical sense), or if it is going to do something else that could touch the sdb1 partition.   So I'm a little concerned.  I've been searching for the answer to this, but I keep running across instructions regarding the install process which don't address this specific issue...I'd appreciate feedback from someone who definitively knows the answer!  Thanks!

ADDENDUM:  A couple of people suggested that I mark the partitions intended for use in the "Something Else" option of the installer (thanks for your fast response, guys!).  However, I don't see where it allows me to do that:  I can choose which partition to format and create a "New Partition Table," but nothing else.

Comment: There's no guarantee the (automatic) installer won't mess with partitions it shouldn't. A safe alternative is to select "something else" and mark for use the / and swap partitions you already have.

Comment: The Installer will only work with the partitions or drives that you specify.  The installer may split the space you allocate into more than one partition for swap.  This will be space that it creates from the space that you have specified.  Your other partitions will be untouched.  The only way your `/dev/sdb1` would be touched by the installer is if you specified the `whole drive` for your installation... or specified partition `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: Hello guys...thanks for your comments!  For the 16.04 installer I have (i386/desktop), it doesn't seem to allow me to specify which partitions to use for installation in the "Something Else" option...I can only mark which partitions I wish to format, and I have the option of creating a "New Partition Table."

Comment: Is the partition it's allowing you to mark for formatting the partition with the previous Ubuntu installation that you want to replace?  If it is, then proceed with that one.

Comment: Hello L.D.:  I can mark any/all of them for formatting (including the Windows partition on sda).  So should I mark the previous Ubuntu partition for formatting?  Is that what will allow me to indicate to the installer that this is the partition I want to use?